# Huge permission issues with Apache/PHP when hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: php, apache, azure, docker

I have a `Docker` image hosted in a app service on `Azure`.

Everything works fine when I run a container for that image on my local machine.

But **everything** breaks down as soon as I put it in Azure.

I got `Permission denied` everywhere, problems with apache that can't read the `.htaccess` file, random `Forbidden` errors on static files and so on...

So in order to find out what's going on I simplified to the point where I simply try to write a file.

The folder structure is the following:

```
/var (www-data:staff, 777)
|  - /www (www-data:staff, 777)
|  |  - /public
|  |  |  - index.php
```

In the `index.php` I've got:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$path = '/var/www';

var_dump(get_current_user());
var_dump(posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name']);
var_dump(is_readable($path));
var_dump(is_writable($path));
var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode'));

file_put_contents($path . '/test.log', 'test');
```

The output is:

```sh
string(8) "www-data"
string(8) "www-data"
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)

Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/test.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/public/index.php on line 14
```

If I change the `file_put_contents` to write in the `var` folder:

```php
[...]
$path = '/var';
[...]
file_put_contents($path . '/test.log', 'test');
```

**It works fine!**

The two folders have the exact same permissions (777), owner (www-data) and group (staff).

I thought about `SELinux` but I don't know if it is installed.

I didn't find any option to enable/disable it in the app service configuration and the `getenforce` or `setenforce` commands are not found when logged in web ssh.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your help.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**:

After a lot of tries, I figured that the problem is specific to the `/var/www` folder.

If I try to write anywhere I should have access to, it works fine, but not in the `/var/www` folder, no matter its access rights.

**But I have more!**

If I **rename** `/var/www` to `/var/www2` and then back to `/var/www`:  **everything works**!

I can create the test file I tried to create above, the site boots normally, log files are written normally, the routing works, etc.

So it seems there is something blocking access to everything under `www` that is not related to the container, but probably to `Azure`.

And this "thing" seem to stop when the folder cease to exist and never come back.

Any idea of what it could be?

**EDIT 2**:

It does't have to be `/var/www`, I have the exact same behavior after changing the `DirectoryRoot` from `/var/www/public` to `/var/app/public`.

Renaming `/var/app` to `/var/app2` and then back to `/var/app` also solves the issue.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: 1) var should **never** be 777. 2) put files to 644 + folders to 755 3) the directory must be in ownership of the user that executes apache/php

Comment: Yeah I know, I had my directories at `711`, public files at `644` and source files at `640` when I deployed. I changed the permissions only for testing, in order to understand the problem. That's only after a **lot** of try and retry that I tested to put /var at 777. It's not meant to be kept that way. Apache executes as `www-data:staff`, still I can't write anywhere under `/var/www`.

Comment: I've edited my question to give new elements, I think the issue is related to `Azure`, but I have no idea of what it can be.